# Complex Rails/Postgres SQL optimization

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Restaurant
    has_many Dish

```
Dish
has_many Photo

Photo
belongs_to Dish

Restaurant 1
  Dish 1
    Photo 1   May 9, 1:00 PM
  Dish 2
    Photo 2   May 9, 2:00 PM
  Dish 3
    Photo 3   May 9, 3:00 PM

Restaurant 2
  Dish 4
    Photo 4   May 9, 1:00 PM
  Dish 5
    Photo 5   May 9, 2:00 PM
  Dish 6
    Photo 6   May 9, 3:00 PM
```

I'm trying to retrieve the latest 50 photos with a limit of 2 dish photos per restaurant. Given the data above I'd be able to retrieve photos with ids `2, 3, 5, and 6`

My current implementation is ugly to say the least.

```
hash = {}
bucket = []
Photo.includes(:dish => [:restaurant]).order("created_at desc").each do |p|
  restaurant_id = p.dish.restaurant.id
  restaurant_count = hash[restaurant_id].present? ? hash[restaurant_id] : 0
  if restaurant_count < 2
    bucket << p
    hash[restaurant_id] = restaurant_count + 1
  end
  # if you've got 50 items short circuit.
end
```

I can't help but feel that there's a much more efficient solution. Any ideas would be appreciated :-).

Comment: This isn't trivial logic to implement even in pure SQL. You might be better off maintaining a specialized queue structure of some sort that always maintains a list of these 50 photos. You can then do the 2-per-restaurant limit when you enequeue a new photo. Obviously this would be optimized for few-writes-many-reads.

Comment: Yes, that was my next step, since I'm really quite clueless when it comes to subqueries.

Comment: If you're down for some Googling to set up the SQL, something like this: http://books.google.com/books?id=thTju-4duY4C&lpg=PP1&ots=nFmsRSwKu0&dq=enterprise%20rails&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false would probably be the best way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way of 'grouping' your query, but at least the following is a bit simpler:

```
def get_photo_bucket
  photo_bucket = restaurant_control = []
  Photos.includes(:dish => [:restaurant]).order("created_at desc").each do |photo|
    if photo_bucket.count < 50 && restaurant_control.count(photo.dish.restaurant.id) < 2
      photo_bucket << photo
      restaurant_control << photo.dish.restaurant.id
    end
  end
  photo_bucket
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will simply return the latest two dishes from each restaurant, not the 50 most recent with a limit of two per.

Comment: Sorry @mikeryz, I misunderstood your constraints. I have edited the answer.